# Execute method in running program instead of launching a new instance

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-7, taskbar

I am writing a weather application. I am integrating it with the taskbar. When you right click on its icon on the taskbar it show you the current temperature, etc. Currently if you click on the text that says "Current: ..." it opens another instance of the application.

Screenshot:

[image: Weather taskbar]

How can I get this to run a procedure or function in my program? So if the user clicks on the "Current: ..." it should open a new form in the same application. It should not open another application?

My code is currently:

```
JumpListCustomCategory userActionsCategory = new JumpListCustomCategory("Weather");
userActionLink.Arguments = "-1";
JumpListLink userActionLink = new JumpListLink(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, Conditions + ": " + reader.ReadToEnd());
userActionLink.IconReference = new IconReference(testicon, 0);
userActionsCategory.AddJumpListItems(userActionLink);
list.AddCustomCategories(userActionsCategory);
list.Refresh();
```

Comment: Are you looking for `NotifyIcon`?

Comment: Hi L.B no I want to show the current temperature to the user using the windows 7 taskbar if you right click. Then when the user clicks on the text the program should open a new form but in the same application. Currently it opens a new application.

Comment: Hi joostehost, not sure if this helps but the first time that came to my mind is this : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=150

Comment: Not really I need to open a new form with the jump list.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [The Weekly Source Code 31- Single Instance WinForms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx). It will allow you to open only one program instance, but using VisualBasic instead of a Mutex.